# How do I use external routes.js so I don't have to define my routes in app.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'd like to do a simple link in express. 
I put into the index.jade

```
a(href='/test', title='View test page') Test
```

created in /routes a test.js

```
/*
* GET test page.
*/

exports.test = function(req, res){
res.render('test', { title: 'Genious test' });
};
```

and a simple test.jade in /views

```
extends layout

block content
h1= title
p Test page
```

I added in app.js

```
app.get('/test', routes.test);
```

If I click on the link I get the error

```
Cannot GET /test
```

Comment: Did you restart node after changing your app.js?  Just a thought because everything looks correct.

Comment: I restarted node but got an error so I had to remove `app.get('/test', routes.test);` however the link is still not working

Comment: Can you show more of your app.js?  What was the error you got when you restarted node?

Comment: the error was: `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/express/myapp/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:252
    throw new Error(msg);
          ^
Error: .get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/express/myapp/myapp/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:252:11` the app.js is basically just what express generated

Comment: `routes.test` is undefined, so please post how you actually define `routes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of creating ***routes/test.js***, add this on to ***routes/index.js***

```
exports.test = function(req, res){
    res.render('test', { title: 'Test' });
};
```

Then **app.get('/test', routes.test);** will work as expected.

Comment: I was wondering if there is an easier solution, this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Ok.  In your app.js add the following lines, and your problems will be solved.

```
var test = require('./routes/test.js')

app.get('/test', test.test);
```

This will definitely allow for your app to run and the link to be active.

Comment: I deleted the require cause the index didn't have a require as well, but this was obviously wrong. It works now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Adding

```
exports.newpage = function(req, res){
  res.render('newpage');
};
```

to /routes/index.js. Then adding

```
app.get('/newpage', routes.newpage);
```

under

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
```

at the bottom of server.js (or app.js).

Answer (score 1):

Months after the fact, I'm going to answer this a different way. You simply wanted it to work and you got a solution for it to work. But, what if you really wanted another `routes.js` to handle more of your routes? Fear not node can handle this!

Assuming this structure,

```
- app.js
- routes/
  -  index.js
  -  foo.js
```

And, let's say you want the syntax in your `app.js`

```
app.get('/test', routes.foo.test);
```

For this, in `routes.js` add,

```
var foo = exports.foo = require('./foo');
```

Then in `app.js` you'll have,

```
var routes = require('./routes');
```

This will work, it'll allow you to say in `app.js`,

```
app.get('/test', routes.foo.test);
```

This will give you another level to organize your routes. I usually like to keep all of my routes organized under the `routes` object, but if you want to import directly into main you can too,

```
var foo = require('./routes/foo');
app.get('/test', foo.test);
```